# Configuration Optimization Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to work out the best way to calculate the cheapest configuration for products which meet a set of criteria.

Imagine the following products:

Product 1 - $1000 -

```
Attribute 1 x 1
Attribute 2 x 5
```

Product 2 - $75 -

```
Attribute 2 x 1
```

Product 3 - $3000 -

```
Attribute 1 x 1
Attribute 2 x 10
Attribute 3 x 1
```

And the following requirements:

```
1x  Attribute 1
10x Attribute 2
```

Obviously the Optimal solution here is `1x Product 1` and `5x Product 2`, but I need to solve this when I have dozens of products and requirements.

Sorry if I haven’t explained this very well, I would really appreciate any suggestions on the best method to calculate this.

Thanks,

Antony

**Edit:**

I looked at the Knapsack problem prior to posting, however the issue with that method is that I don’t have an upper limit (capacity) and each item attribute doesn’t have a set value. For instance I could have a fourth product:

Product 4 - $500 –

```
Attribute 2 x 10
```

So now Attribute 2 is worth $75 when singular or $50 when brought in multiples of 10, so clearly if I wanted 10 of Attribute 2 I would want to get a single Product 4 rather than 10 of product 2, In this example I could use `value x quantity` to determine the weight of the attribute, however some attributes I wouldn't be able to calculate with this method, such as Product 1, because I have no way of determining the value of attribute 1 (it is only ever available with other attributes).

Comment: In this moment which method you're using to solve this?

Comment: Google Knapsack problem or dynamic programming.

Comment: I Havant been able to make an attempt yet as I don't know the best method to use.

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is a modification of a [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) where you have several different wights(in this case the number of each attribute you have in the beginning). It can be solved using dynamic programming. I suggest you read the article about backpack problem and understand how we approach it. I am deliberately only giving you a tip as you have not shown any attempted solution.

EDIT: in fact your problem is quite close to a famous variation of the knapsack problem namely [change making problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem). Consider the products as the available coin values but when selecting a product count it for as many "coins" as is the price of the product.

Comment: Hi,
Pointers are all I'm looking for so thanks!

I've updated my original question as the extra information I tried to add was too long.

Thanks again, I really appreciate your advice.

Comment: I think this is more of a multi-constraint dual of knapsack problem. This is because we want to 'minimize' the total weight ( here cost), given the minimum total value of multiple attributes.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal it seems I am solving the problem the other way around. I have misunderstood the statement it seems. Again :)

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev :) No you are correct since it is a modification of knapsack problem. You just need to add the detail about how it differs from the conventional knapsack problem.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal in fact I believe it is way closer to [coin making problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem). This of course is again a knapsack variation but with a bit different approach.